# How do I clear environment variables previously saved with u-boot?

Tags: environment-variables, u-boot

I am working with an embedded linux kit that is running u-boot.  In order to get everything booting properly, I had to modify some environment variables and store them with the 'saveenv' command.

Now I would like to go back and see what the defaults were, verify that I know exactly what was changed, and figure out a way to change those defaults so that each unit in production won't need to be individually booted and modified.

Is there a way to tell u-boot to clear any saved data so I can see what the defaults are again?  The flash type is QSPI if that makes a difference.

Comment: The U-Boot environment area is validated with a 32-bit CRC, so if you clobber it, just a byte will do, in the nonvolatile storage, then U-Boot will revert to its default settings on startup.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On your kit, try

```
help env
```

and look for "env default".

```
env default [-f] var [...] - [forcibly] reset variable(s) to their default values
```

That sounds like what you are looking for.

```
env default -a
```

does a nonpersistent change, then "printenv" shows the defaults.

To change defaults, you would rebuild your u-boot.bin with changes e.g. to CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS.

Comment: I found the configuration in ./u-boot/include/configs/board-vendor.h.template.  However, in that section for CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS, I see things like:
"loadaddr=@nstart@\0"

Do you know where that 'nstart' and other similar variables are set?  I'd rather not just replace them with a number if there's a better way.

Comment: Current u-boot does not seem to have board-vendor.h, and I don't recognize variable syntax @nstart, sorry.

Comment: It must be something specific to my kit (Avnet Zedboard using Xilinx Petalinux).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

To use default vars without removing them from flash execute

```
env default -a
```

within u-boot and then execute `$bootcmd`.  [Joe Kul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821972/joe-kul)'s solution.

To [erase the vars from the SPI flash](http://zedboard.org/content/u-boot-environment-variables-not-updating-using-petalinux) execute

```
run eraseenv
```

within u-boot and then reboot.

Comment: Note that `run eraseenv`, more specifically `eraseenv`, has to be defined first. It is not an out of the box command.

https://www.denx.de/wiki/publish/DULG/to-delete/UBootCmdGroupEnvironment.html

Comment: @Catalin Ok, the Zynq development environment from Xilinx has it be defined and I don't know how far back up the food chain it goes.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
# add uboot env variable
setenv my_var 1

# printenv my_var
my_var=1

# remove/unset uboot env variable
setenv my_var

# printenv my_var
## Error: "my_var" not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

The `eraseenv` is not defined in my case. According to @Joshua's answer, I find the following command does what `eraseenv` does.

```
env default -a
saveenv
```

Comment: Hello @Iceberg, when I do `env default -a` from linux userspace I get the error as `env: 'default': No such file or directory`. please let me know how to use this command.

Comment: @Preeti I believe I executed these commands in the console of u-boot instead of the command line of linux.

Comment: may be I am confused here. My board is completely booted up and linux user space is loaded(for example I can execute `fw_printenv`) but `env default -a` is showing error. Do I need to enable this in my config file like `include/configs/stm32mp1.h`?

Comment: No, the `env default -a` command cannot be run from within linux. The linux `env` command is entirely unrelated to u-boot. As far as I can tell there is no easy way to reset the u-boot environment from within linux. I think you could probably do it by using `dd` to clear out the appropriate storage, which would cause u-boot to revert to the compiled-in default environment (but I have not tried this)