# uboot does not honour the `CONFIG_DEFAULT_FDT_FILE` option

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot, buildroot

Using board, OrangePI Zero3, I'm running a custom dt file `sun50i-h616-orangepi-zero3-custom.dts`.

I've set the `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH` in the buildroot menuconfig and dtb succesfully compiles.

I'm also able to successfully manually boot this dtb from uboot. Otherwise I get the error at boot `Failed to load '/boot/allwinner/sun50i-h616-orangepi-zero3.dtb'` (as this file shouldnt be present).

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of [re-build buildroot to include custom device tree dts modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77690608/re-build-buildroot-to-include-custom-device-tree-dts-modification) but with far less detail.